# AS400 RPG DSPF Character Level Color Change

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to change the color of individual characters in a field in a subfile.

SCOTT  LAWRENCE
JOHN   SMITH

I like to show CO in SCOTT as RED color and MI in SMITH in RED color and all other character is GREEN. Can this be achieved ? I am having hard to finding a DSPATR at the individual character level instead of field level in the DSPF. Basically, I want to show characters in a field having values CO and MI in a subfile in a different color.

Comment: If using 5250 displays, there is no character-level attribute available for display files. Attributes are at the field level. Use a more pure GUI display technology if such detailed control is required.

Comment: Actually, the display file is shown on the GUI screen. How can character colors be controlled on GUI screen using the same DSPF?

Comment: You can't do it with a 5250 DSPF using just the native features. Technically, I suppose, a "screen scraper" or some similar technology could conceivably emulate character-level controls, perhaps by way of passing 'hidden' fields in the record format; but that'd require adding the fields to the record format, adding RPG code to populate those fields and having some client that interprets and implements whatever those values would mean for whatever the client's output is.

Comment: `...the display file is shown on the GUI screen.` What "GUI screen"?

Comment: AS400 screen's are displayed on a GUI based client (using a 3rd party software called Strategi). The GUI is basically a dump UI which displays the DSPF since the DSPF is precoded to the GUI requirements.So, there is no way a 5250 emulator can control character level colors, correct?

Comment: This question is resolved now. Not possible using DSPF but can change colors of specific character by inserting a blank before then and adding a hexadecimal value of colors.

Comment: By adding a "blank" and inserting a DSPATR() hex value, you are effectively adding a new field to the screen. Each display "field" has a 1-byte leading (and trailing) attribute byte. You then dynamically control a new "field", one that's not individually defined in the DSPF DDS.

Comment: I am not adding a field in the DSPF and no modifications done to DSPF. I am inserting blank in the field in the program for example SCOTT becomes S CO TT and then inset hex value of red after S and hex value of green after O. The result is the characters STT will be green and CO will be red.

Comment: That's right. You're not adding a field to the "DSPF". You're adding a new field to the "screen".

Answer (score 0):

The only way, in 5250 display to show CO in SCOTT as RED color would be to write hexadecimal value within your string, such as:
    'S' + x'28' + 'CO' + x'20 + 'TT'
(x28:red, x20:normal - cf. http://www.classanova.com/view?id=1382&p=5)

This will change the color but you will also have 1 space for any hexadecimal code:
S CO TT

For GUI, you might have better alternatives. Maybe generating an HTML page with the color changes could an option.

Answer (score 0):

if your "NAME" field is a fixed length 10 characters, you'd make a data structure
for each character...

DS  1 10 NAME

```
1  1 Name1

2  2 Name2  ... etc.
```

Then you'd load NAME  with your input name SMITH.
The name breaks down into individual fields. 
Use 10 display fields next to each other & define what color they would be. 
Load the screen fields with your DS fields  SName1 = Name1    SName2 = Name2 
Display the fields with colors you selected. 
SName1 SName2 SName3 .....